# Angular 4 - Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 200 Ok for URL: null

Tags: angular, jsonp

I've got an Angular 4 app with using `jsonp` for api requests. Every api call looks similar and has the basic structure of:

```
requestInteractions() {
    let apiPath = `xyz`;
    this.setParams(); //


    return this
        .jsonp.request(this.fullRequestUrl(apiPath), { search: this.params })
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            data => this.ngRedux.dispatch(this.actions.initializeStateFromInteractions(data)),
            err => this.handleError(err),
        );
}
```

Some requests do not process the data, so the `subscribe` block looks like:

```
.subscribe(
    data => {},
    err => this.handleError(err),
);
```

JS errors are being logged to the server and I am getting the error `Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 200 Ok for URL: null` multiple times a day. It never happens on localhost and also when checking on production, I can't reproduce the error. Overall the app is stable and handles thousands of calls per day.

Thanks in advance for you ideas.

Comment: It would be good if you can also log the response when the error occurs. Since the log says url 'null', could this be the result if your api url is null somewhere in your code, if it's dynamically generated? In your map() call, error will be thrown if the response is not valid JSON, like a blank page or random strings.

Comment: Thanks @DanielH.J. I've just realised that the api url is being set from the redux store and the call is probably happening right before the url is set to its proper value..